# How do you get the ids of the individual scripts inside a GAS project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I just want to be able to go through the individual gs files as blobs to summarize some information about the entire project. I think I CAN do this with drive api but I need to know the individual files first.

Comment: What do you mean by "the ids of the individual scripts..."? Also show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I would do that with the app script API it’s very easy to get the contents of all the files and JSON format. How do you get a list of all of the files of a certain time using list method of Drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Yes, you can do this with Drive API:

First you need to use `DriveApp.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.script")` to get the list of Apps Script projects in your Drive.

**Sample List:**

```
{
 "kind": "drive#fileList",
 "etag": "\"kjsas92/f3zGUXczKMxEB_9ZTMRFOF3d1ZU\"",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=mimeType%3D'application/vnd.google-apps.script'+and+'me'+in+owners",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#file",
   "id": "1vi0uwcMdHsRv1YFtgq7XdiTGSdqgjIYpdQNC0A_Udn79LOhH0vYL132D",
   "etag": "\"kjsas92/MTM3MDk3ODY5ODQyNg\"",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1vi0uwcMdHsRv1YFtgq7XdiTGSdqgjIYpdQNC0A_Udn79LOhH0vYL132D",
   "alternateLink": "https://script.google.com/a/google.com/d/1vi0uwcMdHsRv1YFtgq7XdiTGSdqgjIYpdQNC0A_Udn79LOhH0vYL132D/edit?usp=drivesdk",
   "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_script_list.png",
   "title": "Mail merge",
   "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.script",
   "description": "",
   "labels": {
    "starred": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "trashed": true,
    "restricted": false,
    "viewed": true
   },
   "createdDate": "2013-06-11T19:24:45.188Z",
   "modifiedDate": "2013-06-11T19:24:58.426Z",
   "modifiedByMeDate": "2013-06-11T19:24:58.426Z",
   "lastViewedByMeDate": "2013-06-11T19:24:58.426Z",
   "parents": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#parentReference",
     "id": "0APdyIOzo7bWDUk9PVA",
     "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1vi0uwcMdHsRv1YFtgq7XdiTGSdqgjIYpdQNC0A_Udn79LOhH0vYL132D/parents/0APdyIOzo7bWDUk9PVA",
     "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0APdyIOzo7bWDUk9PVA",
     "isRoot": true
    }
   ],
   "exportLinks": {
    "application/json": "https://script.google.com/feeds/download/export?id=1234567890abcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&format=json"
   },
   "userPermission": {
    "kind": "drive#permission",
    "etag": "\"kjsas92/259X2r5DVstv1CcIQTjt_RQPSW8\"",
    "id": "me",
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1vi0uwcMdHsRv1YFtgq7XdiTGSdqgjIYpdQNC0A_Udn79LOhH0vYL132D/permissions/me",
    "role": "owner",
    "type": "user"
   },
   "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
   "ownerNames": [
    "John Doe"
   ],
   "owners": [
    {
     "kind": "drive#user",
     "displayName": "John Doe",
     "picture": {
      "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-yd1rIb6Pe2Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGs/PP5vTuZonik/s64/photo.jpg"
     },
     "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
     "permissionId": "1234566789"
    }
   ],
   "lastModifyingUserName": "John Doe",
   "lastModifyingUser": {
    "kind": "drive#user",
    "displayName": "John Doe",
    "picture": {
     "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-yd1rIb6Pe2Y/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGs/PP5vTuZonik/s64/photo.jpg"
    },
    "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
    "permissionId": "1234566789"
   },
   "editable": true,
   "writersCanShare": true,
   "shared": false,
   "explicitlyTrashed": true,
   "appDataContents": false
  }
 ]
}
```

Then each individual project has `exportLinks` property that has a link to the scripts inside. You need to fetch that URL to get a JSON response that has the individual files and script ID's.

**Sample JSON:**

```
{
  "files": [
    {
      "id":"9basdfbd-749a-4as9b-b9d1-d64basdf803",
      "name":"Code",
      "type":"server_js",
      "source":"function doGet() {\n  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(\u0027index\u0027);\n}\n"
    },
    {
      "id":"3asf7c0d-1afb-4a9-8431-5asdfc79e7ae",
      "name":"index",
      "type":"html",
      "source":"\u003chtml\u003e\n  \u003cbody\u003e\n    Hello, world!\n  \u003c/body\u003e\n\u003c/html\u003e"
    }
  ]
}
```

### References:

[Import and Export Projects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/import-export)

[Get Files by Type](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByType(String))

[Files Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files)